# Export a *.txt file convert commas to dots

Tags: c#

I'm using this code to export a *.txt

```
TextWriter sw = new StreamWriter(@"C:\fiscal.txt");       

int rowcount = dataGridView1.Rows.Count;

for (int i = 0; i < rowcount - 1; i++)
{
    sw.Write("{0,-20}", dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value.ToString());       
}                

sw.Close();
```

My text file contain a value number with comma example 3,20

How can i change it? And to export it with dot 3.20

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simple fix would be to apply .NET/C# `String.Replace(",", ".")` method, but only if there are no other cases of using "," in that particular text; thus, the following line will do the job rather quick (best performance):

```
dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value.ToString().Replace(",", ".")
```

It will also work fine if the values are entered with, for example, dollar sign, like: $3,20 (would be converted into $3.20).

Alternatively, you may use `Parse()` (or `TryParse())` methods in conjunction with `CultureInfo` class, which is sort of universal solution, but could be an "overkill" for this particular task, and also will take much longer to complete (i.e. will cause significant performance degradation). Also, the parsing could be a bit problematic in case the values are entered with a leading currency sign (like $3,20 mentioned above).

Hope this may help.

Comment: The safest one would probably be applying specific culture info that uses dot as delimiter.

Comment: Thank Sir it Works 100%.

Comment: You are welcome. Good luck with your project. Best regards,

Answer (score 0):

As this is monetary data you could convert the text to decimals using `Decimal.TryParse` with the culture set to one that has decimal commas (French say):

```
NumberStyles style = NumberStyles.Number | NumberStyles.AllowCurrencySymbol;

decimal result;
if (decimal.TryParse(text, style, new CultureInfo("fr-FR"), out result))
{

}
```

Then write it out using a culture that uses decimal points (English say):

```
string outputText = result.ToString("C", new CultureInfo("en-GB"));
```

Though this would have the side effect of changing the currency symbol. To make sure that stayed the same you'd have to clone the culture you were using for output and change it's currency symbol.

Answer (score 0):

Use [`CultureInfo.InvariantCulture`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo.invariantculture.aspx) in `ToString` and `Parse`. So in your case it looks like this:

```
sw.Write("{0,-20}", dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
```